# Getting error on hitting Google Vision Api

Tags: node.js, google-vision

```
  const options = {
  hostname: 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<some key>',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res : any) => {
  res.on('data', (chunk : any) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// Write data to request body
req.write(JSON.stringify(body))
req.end()
```

I am trying to use one of the google vision feature i.e. Text Detection. But when ever I am hitting that api I am getting this error. I double checked the url and other data.

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<> https://vision.googleapis.
com/v1/images:annotate?key=<key>:80
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname:
   'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<key>',
  host:
   'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<key>',
  port: 80 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work, there are only a couple of changes necessary, for example we'll use the https module rather than the http module.

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'vision.googleapis.com',
    path: '/v1/images:annotate?key=' + API_KEY,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
};

let data = "";
const req = https.request(options, (res: any) => {
    res.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${data}`);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// Write data to request body
req.write(JSON.stringify(body))
req.end()
```

Comment: I should have used https earlier itself.

Comment: Oh maybe so.. it's sometimes hard to see these things when you're debugging though.. :-)..  The Google Vision API is really useful... happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for helping and updating the answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.. !

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the request to:

```
  const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }
};

const req = http.request(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<some key>`, options, (res : any) => {
  res.on('data', (chunk : any) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
});
```

because `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<some key>` is a full URL, not a valid hostname.

Comment: it was not allowing to make https call